# Getting Bokeh Duplicate Edit Error

Tags: python, bokeh

I am trying to plot multiple charts using bokeh gridplot layout. The charts are successfully viewed from Notebook but does not render in browser.
I get "**Bokeh Duplicate Edit Error**" in Browser. Below is the code that I am using.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, output_notebook,show
from bokeh.charts import Line
from bokeh.layouts import gridplot
import pandas as pd

df= pd.read_csv("C:/tps.csv")
df1= pd.read_csv("C:/abc.csv")

p1=Line(df,title="Test1")
p2=Line(df1,title="Test2")

grid = gridplot([[p1,  p2]], toolbar_location=None)
# show the results
output_file('Test.html')
output_notebook()
show(grid)
```

I am not able to find out what mistake I am making. Any pointers will really help.
Thanks for your help

Comment: This seems like a possible bug. However, in order to help I'd have to be  to run code and reproduce the problem, which isn't possible with the code above because the data files are not supplied. Please file a bug report with a complete, minimal, example code on the [GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues)

Comment: Replacing the 'pd.read_csv' calls with 'np.arange' calls and using bokeh 0.12, this code produces two line charts and no errors.  Perhaps the v0.12 fixed the underlying issue.

Answer (score 3):

I was even facing the same issue, the reason was that I had multiple `show()` commands, I just kept a single `show()` and it worked fine.
Or else you can either fetch and clear the document:

```
from bokeh.io import curdoc
curdoc().clear()
```

Hope that helps.